# How to adjust Mendeley to get the specific style?

Tags: citations, reference-managers

I normally use Mendeley for citing references in my research work. Normally, It will be like that, which is under *American Sociological Association 6th Edition* style.

> Neuhaus, J. M., L. Sticher, F. Meins, Jr, and T. Boller. 1991. “A
> Short C-Terminal Sequence Is Necessary and Sufficient for the
> Targeting of Chitinases to the Plant Vacuole.” Proceedings of the
> National Academy of Sciences of the United States of America
> 88(22):10362. doi: 10.1073/PNAS.88.22.10362.

However, from the specific requirement of PNAS, they require under this style

> J.-M. Neuhaus, L. Sticher, F. Meins, Jr., T. Boller, A short
> C-terminal sequence is necessary and sufficient for the targeting of
> chitinases to the plant vacuole. Proc. Natl. Acad. Sci. U.S.A. 88,
> 10362–10366 (1991).

I am wondering how to adjust the style of Mendeley to adjust the reference as requested? If not, is there anyway to do so automatically?

Answer (score 2):

The referencing style within Mendeley can be adjusted using the Microsoft Word Plugin. For example, if you have the Mendeley MS Word Plugin for Mac installed: select the 'References' tab, find the Style drop-down menu and select 'More Styles...', then navigate to the 'Get More Styles' tab, and use the search bar to type in 'Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences'. The referencing style you are looking for should come up as an option, and you can install it by clicking the Install button to the right of the name. Once installed, you can select 'Use this Style', and all of the references in your document will be adjusted to follow the PNAS guidelines.